# Remove visible underline between menu buttons

Tags: button, text, hyperlink, block, underline

I am unable to remove the underline in between the clickable buttons. It seems to continue as a block, but I can't remove display:block; as it makes only the text clickable.

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"cfont";
    src: url("font/Guerra_Santa.ttf");
}

body {
    margin:0;
}

#menu {
    background-color:black;
    height:70px;
    width:800px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
}

#menu li {
    font-family:cfont;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:70px;
    height:70px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#C28285;
}

#menu ul li a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wdwgmvtk/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't self close the anchor.

Change:

```
<li><a href="index.html"/>Home</li>
```

To:

```
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wdwgmvtk/13/